# Get notification when my app server port down

Tags: javascript, web-services, server

I have an app server running on port :4567/. Frequently my server gets down and unable to monitor this. Is there a way to notify me a email are message to show that my server gets down.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an external service such as https://cronitor.io/ to do this. Another one is https://uptimerobot.com/